# JComboBox causes a runtime error

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jcombobox

I'm trying some GUI development in Java and when I added the following code, I got a runtime error during initialization of the class:

```
public class Search_Album_Main_Tab extends JPanel{
    JComboBox   search_list;
    JTextArea   searched_data;
    JButton     search_button;
    Results_Main_Tab rmt;
    Search_Action_Listener listener;

    public Search_Album_Main_Tab(Results_Main_Tab results_main_tab)
    {
        String[] search_options = {"Album", "Artist", "Genre", "ID", "Year"};
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        rmt = results_main_tab;
        listener = new Search_Action_Listener();

        /*  Searched data   */
        searched_data = new JTextArea();

        /*  Search button   */
        search_button = new JButton("Search Album");
        search_button.addActionListener(listener);

        /*  Drop down menu  */
        search_list = new JComboBox(search_options);

        add(search_list);
        add(searched_data);
        add(search_button);     
    }

    private class Search_Action_Listener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
            if (event.getSource() == search_button)
            {

            }

        }

    }

}
```

The error I get is:

```
dcm_gui.GUI at localhost:53806  
    Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
        CUIAquaComboBox.applySizeFor(JComponent, CoreUIConstants$Size) line: 454    
        CUIAquaUtilControlSize.applyUISizing(JComponent, CoreUIConstants$Size) line: 99 
        CUIAquaUtilControlSize.access$200(JComponent, CoreUIConstants$Size) line: 13    
        CUIAquaUtilControlSize$PropertySizeListener.applyComponentSize(JComponent, Object) line: 121    
        CUIAquaUtilControlSize.addSizePropertyListener(JComponent) line: 25 
        CUIAquaComboBox.installListeners() line: 47 
        CUIAquaComboBox(BasicComboBoxUI).installUI(JComponent) line: 229    
        CUIAquaComboBox.installUI(JComponent) line: 30  
        JComboBox(JComponent).setUI(ComponentUI) line: 653  
        JComboBox.setUI(ComboBoxUI) line: 238   
        JComboBox.updateUI() line: 247  
        JComboBox.init() line: 212  
        JComboBox.<init>(Object[]) line: 178    
        Search_Album_Main_Tab.<init>(Results_Main_Tab) line: 36 
        GUI.main(String[]) line: 28 
    Daemon Thread [AWT-AppKit] (Running)    
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/bin/java (Oct 10, 2010 11:55:27 PM)
```

Does anyone has any idea why?

Binyamin

Comment: You're trying to call a method, or access a field, of an object which is `null`, somewhere in the `Search_Album_Main_Tab` constructor. What's at line 36?

Comment: Thanks, I can see that, but I don't see anything that I didn't initialize before using. In this specific case I used the constructor with a defined string array.

Comment: Line 36 is `search_list = new JComboBox(search_options);`, and search_options is a string array: `String[] search_options = {"Album", "Artist", "Genre", "ID", "Year"};`

Comment: Are you trying to use a custom look & feel?

Comment: This is my first GUI implementation so I'm not really sure, I didn't use anything except of the AWT and Swing packages, are they considered  as part of the 'look and feel'?

Comment: @MByD : The "look and feel" is the way devs can change the way Java GUIs look. Because all of those classes starting with "CUIAqua" are part of an environment specific L&F library. Are you developing on a Mac? Somewhere in your code, do you have a line which has "UIManager.setLookAndFeel" in it? Or are you use a GUI designer like the one in NetBeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue with your custom look and feel. I encountered a similar problem once before, when using custom looks and feels. It is described here:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4711700

That was for the JFileChooser widget, not a combo box, but it might be related.

The first thing you should try is reverting to the default "metal" look and feel. If that works, then it might be a problem with that specific L&F. I haven't used the CUIAqua L&F before, but I think it's the official Apple Java L&F. You might also like to try switching it out for [QuaQua](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/). It's an alternative Mac-like L&F, which might (depending on the actual bug) avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think Erica is right about the non-standard look & feel.  `CUIAquaComboBox` doesn't sound like a standard element.

If you're not sure what look & feel (LAF) you are using, call `System.out.println(UIManager.getLookAndFeel());` to check.

More importantly, try calling this in your main method before your GUI starts and see if it makes a difference:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

This will use the native LAF for your current operating system (if one can be found - and that should work fine if you're using Windows, Mac, Linux, Solaris etc.)